# How to name pages in dynamically created multipage?

Tags: vba

this is my first question here, so please don't flame me right away. ^^°

I am currently working on a project with multiple multipages, in which i want to create multipages and add new pages to them dynamically. So first things first: How do I name the pages of a dynamically created multipage?

This is the code so far:

```
Option Explicit

Dim PageCountMachine As Long
Dim n As Long

Public MPMachine As MSForms.MultiPage

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

n = 0

Set MPMachine = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.MultiPage.1")

With MPMachine
    
    .Top = 100
    .Left = 5
    .Width = 380
    .Height = 450
    .Name = "Machines"
    
End With

End Sub
```

Thank you in advance for putting up with this. -^^-

Comment: `.Pages.Add "tstPage", "My New Page"` within your `With...End With` block.  `tstPage` must be a unique name (I think).

Comment: I actually found out myself. I simply add

```

For n = 0 To MPMachines.Count - 1
    
    MPMachines.Pages(n).Name = "Seite" & n + 1
    MPMachines.Pages(n).Caption = "Maschine" & n + 1
    
Next

```

after the End With to name the pages. 
But still thanks for your reply. :)

Comment: @Lord-Sanguine Welcome to SO. Great, that you found the solution. Please add it as a proper answer to this question, so others will find it.